# apache (ampps) can't acces one of my folder

Tags: apache, wamp, internal-server-error

I installed AMPPS
I work with some folders without any problem (magento, phpmyadmin, etc).

But with one folder a website downloaded from from the server, I can not access it, also it is not listed in localhost.

When I access the folder which gives me problems, the browser give me this error: 500 Internal Server Error

And from Apache error.log, I receive this:

```
[Wed Oct 16 22:51:25.062078 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8132:tid 396] AH00455: Apache/2.4.6 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.3.27 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Oct 16 22:51:25.062078 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8132:tid 396] AH00456: Server built: Jul 24 2013 14:06:52
[Wed Oct 16 22:51:25.062078 2013] [core:notice] [pid 8132:tid 396] AH00094: Command line: 'apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/apache'
[Wed Oct 16 22:51:25.065078 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8132:tid 396] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 7960
[Wed Oct 16 22:51:26.214144 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7960:tid 408] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

Comment: Those messages are not errors, thats the result of a normal Apache startup.

Comment: Check the folder in question for a `.htaccess` file. If one exists review it an make sure it makes sense on the PC you are now running on